# How does ListNode function work while merging two lists?

Tags: javascript

**Problem description:**

> Merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a new sorted list. The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.

**Sample Input:** l1 = [1,2,4], l2 = [1,3,4]

**Sample Output**: [1,1,2,3,4,4]

**Example Solution:**

```js
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
function ListNode(val, next) {
  this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
  this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
}

const mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    if (l1 === null) {
        return l2;
    }
    if (l2 === null) {
        return l1;
    }
    if (l1.val < l2.val) {
        l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
        return l1;
    }
    else {
        l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next)
        return l2;
    }
};
console.log(mergeTwoLists([1,2,4], [1,3,4]))
```

**Example output:**

```
Soultion accepted
Runtime: 92ms
```

[image: Program screenshot]

**Question:**
Can anyone explain how does `Listnode(val, next)` work? How does it help us, for example, to add another value to exit list, and by adding I mean finding where to place 3 from `l2` (it's not just being inserted in the end but inserted between 2 and 4 in `l1`)?

Comment: `[...l1,...l2].sort();`if you're looking for *ES6* solution!

Comment: Why don't you just concat?

Comment: where is the list part?it does not work with simple arrays.

Comment: Why are you passing arrays to `mergeTwoLists`? It clearly expects `ListNode` instances. Is this really the complete example solution?

Comment: @Bergi yes, this is the code that got accepted by Leetcode as a solution to the problem

Comment: @JoshJohnson That's weird, as it does clearly not work.

Comment: @Bergi I've updated my question to give you a perspective

Comment: Well that's not doing `mergeTwoLists([1,2,4], [1,3,4])` anywhere, and not defining `ListNode` itself. The comment on that function just declares the structure of the arguments you're being passed, namely two singly-linked lists of nodes.

Comment: Are you familiar with how merging two sorted lists is supposed to work in general?

Answer (score -1):

By having arrays, you could use the arrays and splice the first array with the value of the second.

```js
function merge(a, b) {
    if (!b) return a;
    let i = 0,
        j = 0;

    while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
        if (a[i] < b[j]) { i++; continue; }
        a.splice(i, 0, b[j++]);
    }
    while (j < b.length) a.splice(i++, 0, b[j++]);
    return a;
}

console.log(...merge([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 3, 4]));
```

The other opportunity is to create node lists from the array and use the given merging function.

```js
function ListNode(val, next) {
    this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
    this.next = (next === undefined ? null : next)
}

function createList(values) {
    return values.reduceRight((next, val) => new ListNode(val, next), undefined);
}

const
    mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
        if (l1 === null) return l2;
        if (l2 === null) return l1;

        if (l1.val < l2.val) {
            l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
            return l1;
        }
        l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next)
        return l2;
    };

console.log(mergeTwoLists(createList([1, 2, 4]), createList([1, 3, 4])));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```